# Running a system command in Hadoop using spark_apply from sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, sparklyr

I want to run a Java tool on data stored in a Hadoop cluster. I am trying to do it using the spark_apply function from sparklyr, but I am a bit confused by the syntax.

Before running the spark code, I've set up a conda environment following the instructions here: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/09/how-to-distribute-your-r-code-with-sparklyr-and-cdsw/ . I don't have access to parcels, so I need to use the second option described in the article. The conda environment also contains the Java tool I want to use.

Let's take for example the iris data:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(datasets)
data(iris)
config <- spark_config()
config[["spark.r.command"]] <- "./r_env.zip/r_env/bin/Rscript"
config[["spark.yarn.dist.archives"]] <- "r_env.zip"
config$sparklyr.apply.env.R_HOME <- "./r_env.zip/r_env/lib/R"
config$sparklyr.apply.env.RHOME <- "./r_env.zip/r_env"
config$sparklyr.apply.env.R_SHARE_DIR <- "./r_env.zip/r_env/lib/R/share"
config$sparklyr.apply.env.R_INCLUDE_DIR <- "./r_env.zip/r_env/lib/R/include"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", config = config)

# Write iris table to HDFS, partitioning by Species
iris_tbl_tmp = copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite=T)
spark_write_table(iris_tbl_tmp, "iris_byspecies", partition_by="Species")
iris_tbl = sc %>% tbl("iris_byspecies")
iris_tbl
```

Since the Java tool cannot read data from HDFS, I actually have to save each dataset to a file, run the Java tool, then read the data again:

```
myfunction = function(x) { 
    write.table(x, "tempfile.txt")
    system2("{PATH}/myjavatool.java")
    res = read.table("output_of_java_command.txt")
    res
}
myoutput = spark_apply(iris_tbl, myfunction, group_by=Species)
```

My question is about the PATH to the Java tool. How can I see where sparklyr stores the conda environment?

Moreover, is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Running Spark on YARN]https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html() guide, `spark.yarn.dist.archives`:

> Comma separated list of archives to be extracted into the working directory of each executor.

So the files should be just in the working directory of your app.

Comment: Thanks. When using sparklyr, I couldn't find them in that location. However I could figure out the location by looking at .libPaths().

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `sparklyr::spark_apply` with `packages = FALSE`,
which means sparklyr::spark_apply will use your archive package(r_env.zip) instead of your `.libPaths()`

Comment: Know how:
* 1. spark driver will upload your r_env.zip to a HDFS path
* 2. spark worker collect previous HDFS file to local container path
* 3. spark worker extract your zip file : r_env.zip to ./r_env.zip/r_env/ 
* 4. spark worker will call Rscript by R_HOME and other environment settings.